# Selecting random DB entry in Symfony2 - Getting an error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have been trying to pull out a random row, I have used this:

This is the example code I found which did not really help ( I found here: https://gist.github.com/pierroweb/1518601)

```
class QuestionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneRandom()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $max = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT MAX(q.id) FROM EnzimQuestionBundle:Question q
            ')
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
        return $em->createQuery('
            SELECT q FROM EnzimQuestionBundle:Question q 
            WHERE q.id >= :rand
            ORDER BY q.id ASC
            ')
            ->setParameter('rand',rand(0,$max))
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Now I have something like this:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $max = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM GreenMonkeyDevGlassShopBundle:Product p')->getSingleScalarResult();
    return $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM GreenMonkeyDevGlassShopBundle:Product p INNER JOIN (SELECT p2.categories. FROM GreenMonkeyDevGlassShopBundle:Product p.categories WHERE :cid IN(pc) p.id >= :rand ORDER BY p.id ASC')
        ->setParameter('cid', $category_id)
        ->setParameter('rand',rand(0,$max))
        ->setMaxResults(intval($limit))
        ->getSingleResult();
```

I keep getting this error though: 
`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping::addRootEntityFromClassMetadata() in /var/www/gmd-milkywayglass/src/GreenMonkeyDev/GlassShopBundle/Entity/CategoryRepository.php line 42`

Any thoughts on what I can be doing wrong? I know that Doctrine does not have a get random method. Maybe there is some simple solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to write your own DQL function in order to use RAND() in your query :

```
namespace My\Custom\Doctrine2\Function;

/**
 * RandFunction ::= "RAND" "(" ")"
 */
class Rand extends FunctionNode
{

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'RAND()';
    }
}
```

After you have to register this DQL function in symfony2 config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # ...
    orm:
        #...
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                RAND: My\Custom\Doctrine2\Function
```

For more informations, read the following links

[DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

[How to Register Custom DQL Functions in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)

Comment: Really hoping I wouldn't have to do this. Thank you!